# Why does javac -proc:only option still parse java files when class files already exist?

Tags: java, annotations, javac

I've got a large java project, and need to perform annotation processing separately to compiling the code.

So I thought about using the`-proc` option of the `javac` compiler as follows:

1. `javac -proc:none ...` -- to generate the class files.
2. `javac -proc:only -processor x.y.z.MyAnnotationProcessor ...` -- to examine the class files generated in the previous step and generate code.

But it appears that the `javac -proc:only` option still parses .java files:

```
$ javac -proc:only -processor x.y.z.MyAnnotationProcessor ... 
[parsing started RegularFileObject[Foo.java]]
[parsing completed 14ms]
[search path for source files: target\classes]
[search path for class files: ... ]
...
Round 1:
    input files: {Foo}
    annotations: []
    last round: false
```

I would have thought, since a *Foo.class* file exists in *targets/classes* and has a timestamp later then the corresponding *Foo.java* file, that parsing the source file would not be necessary? Is javac really loading the file from disk, parsing it, and constructing an class model in memory, without actually writing the class model to a file? Or does the parsing message relate to the loading of the class file from disk?

The reason this is an issue for me is that I have a source tree with thousands of .java files, and parsing these files twice (once for `-proc:none` and once for `proc:only` invocations) takes a long time.

Is there a way of running the annotation processor so that it uses the class files generated from the previous `javac -proc:none` execution, without (apparently) parsing the same source files again?

Note: I am using JDK 1.7.0_45.

**Edit #1**

Some more detail:

`javac -proc:none` command and output:

```
C:\foo> javac -proc:none -verbose src\main\java\x\y\z\*.java
[parsing started RegularFileObject[src\main\java\x\y\z\Bar.java]]
[parsing completed 15ms]
[parsing started RegularFileObject[src\main\java\x\y\z\Baz.java]]
[parsing completed 0ms]
[parsing started RegularFileObject[src\main\java\x\y\z\Foo.java]]
[parsing completed 1ms]
[search path for source files: .]
[search path for class files: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\resources.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\rt.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\jsse.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\jce.jar,C:\Program    Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\charsets.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\jfr.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\classes,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar,.]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/Object.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/Deprecated.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/annotation/Retention.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/annotation/Target.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/annotation/Annotation.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/AutoCloseable.class)]]
[wrote RegularFileObject[src\main\java\x\y\z\Bar.class]]
[checking x.y.z.Baz]
[wrote RegularFileObject[src\main\java\x\y\z\Baz.class]]
[checking x.y.z.Foo]
[wrote RegularFileObject[src\main\java\x\y\z\Foo.class]]
[total 271ms]
```

`javac -proc:only` command and output:

```
C:\foo>javac -processorpath processor.jar -proc:only -processor x.y.z.MyAnnotationProcessor -verbose src\main\java\x\y\z\*.java
[parsing started RegularFileObject[src\main\java\x\y\z\Bar.java]]
[parsing completed 13ms]
[parsing started RegularFileObject[src\main\java\x\y\z\Baz.java]]
[parsing completed 1ms]
[parsing started RegularFileObject[src\main\java\x\y\z\Foo.java]]
[parsing completed 1ms]
[search path for source files: .]
[search path for class files: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\resources.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\rt.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\jsse.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\jce.jar,C:\Program    Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\charsets.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\jfr.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\classes,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar,.]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/Object.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/Deprecated.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/annotation/Retention.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/annotation/Target.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/annotation/Annotation.class)]]
Round 1:
    input files: {x.y.z.Bar, x.y.z.Baz, x.y.z.Foo}
    annotations: [java.lang.Deprecated]
    last round: false
```

I also tried adding the `-classpath src\main\java\x\y\z` and `-implicit:none` options but java files were still parsed.

**Edit #2**

Using the `-sourcepath src\main\java\` and `-cp src\main\java\` options as suggested:

```
C:\foo>javac -processorpath processor.jar -proc:only -processor x.y.z.MyAnnotationProcessor -verbose -sourcepath src\main\java -cp src\main\java src\main\java\x\y\z\*.java
[parsing started RegularFileObject[src\main\java\x\y\z\Bar.java]]
[parsing completed 14ms]
[parsing started RegularFileObject[src\main\java\x\y\z\Baz.java]]
[parsing completed 0ms]
[parsing started RegularFileObject[src\main\java\x\y\z\Foo.java]]
[parsing completed 0ms]
[search path for source files: src\main\java]
[search path for class files: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\resources.jar, ... etc ..., src\main\java ]
```

I had used an incorrect setting for `-sourcepath` in **Edit #1**, but with the correct `-sourcepath` as suggested I observe that the source files are still loaded and parsed.

I don't see a way of invoking `javac` without specifying java source files, so they will always be loaded and parsed. Perhaps the `javac -proc:only` option may be understood as *"java files will be loaded and parsed and annotation processing performed, but the corresponding class files for the parsed java files are not written to disk"* ?

Comment: I'd be interested to see what's in the '...' of the javac command. The 'search path for source files' trace indicates that you've got it wrong. It shouldn't include `target\classes`, and the 'search path for class files' should.

Comment: I've added more detail in "Edit #1", reflecting a simpler process. Hope that helps!

Comment: This is pointless while you continue to post ... instead of the actual information.

Comment: Apologies. I have added the missing output (which includes loading of JDK jars, unzipping jars, etc). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *told* it to process .java files, so it processed .java files. What did you expect? You named them in the command line: `src\main\java\x\y\z\*.java.` You can tell it to process .class files instead, if that's what you want it to do, or a mixture.

NB there are a few other issues, and these apply to both `-proc:none` and `-proc:only.`

```
javac -processorpath processor.jar -proc:only -processor x.y.z.MyAnnotationProcessor -verbose src\main\java\x\y\z\*.java
```

That should be

```
javac -processorpath processor.jar -proc:only -processor x.y.z.MyAnnotationProcessor -verbose -sourcepath src\main\java -cp src\main\java src\main\java\x\y\z\*.java
```

or, better still, execute the command from within the `src\main\java` directory and omit the `-sourcepath` and `-cp` arguments. If you specified the `-d` option when compiling (`-proc:none`), you should specify the same directory in the `-cp` option when doing `-proc:only`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had originally tried "-sourcepath" but mistakenly set it to "src\main\java\x\y\z". I tried setting it to "src\main\java" as suggested but the output still shows loading and parsing of java source files (see Edit#2 in original question).

Comment: So which of the three files that were processed should not have been parsed, and why not?

Comment: None of them. Class files already exist, which are newer than the source files. I was wondering if there was a way to run the annotation processor separately to the compiling, so that the annotation processing would load the class files generated previously instead of parsing the source code again. Maybe javac is the wrong tool for this, but it's what the maven plugins that I am using will delegate to eventually.

Comment: Actually ... the annotation that I am targeting has a retention policy of COMPILE, meaning it will be stripped from the class file. So loading class files to the annotation processor is not going to work. Instead of separating the javac executions into proc:none and proc:only, I will try to do the processing in one step (which may cause some other problems, since I am generating test code that is not part of the normal compile step).

Comment: But you named them in the command line: `src\main\java\x\y\z\*.java`. You told it to process .java files, so it processed .java files. What did you expect? You can tell it to process .class files instead, if that's what you want it to do, or a mixture.

Comment: Yes, you are right. If I had specified a class file, e.g. "javac -proc:only ... x.y.z.Bar" then there is no parsing of the source files. Surprised that I forget that option ... it's been a while since I used javac directly. If you make this comment an answer then I will mark it as such.

Comment: OK did that, see above.

Comment: Marked as answered ... although the next hurdle now is to get `maven-compiler-plugin` to process _.class_ files instead of _.java_ files, since I'm not actually using `javac` directly.